# CSS, how to center the button inside the div box?

Tags: html, css

this is my first time posting I'm fairly new in front-end web development. I'm having a hard time positioning some of my elements, especially this one every time I change something it doesn't meet my desired position for my button I just need to center it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: #1B244A;
  width: 575px;
  height: 385px;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
}

.scoreBox {
  background: black;
  width: 155px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.scoreBox h1 {
  font-size: 90px;
  color: red;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-family: 'cursed timer', sans-serif;
}

.scoreBtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.scoreBtn button {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-color: #9AABD8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.newGame {}

.newGame button {}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="homeTitle">

      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <div class="scoreBox">
        <h1 id="scoreHome">0</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="scoreBtn">
        <button onclick="plusOneHome()">+1</button>
        <button onclick="plusTwoHome()">+2</button>
        <button onclick="plusThreeHome()">+3</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="guestTitle">
      <h3>GUEST</h3>
      <div class="scoreBox">
        <h1 id="scoreAway">0</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="scoreBtn">
        <button onclick="plusOneAway()">+1</button>
        <button onclick="plusTwoAway()">+2</button>
        <button onclick="plusThreeAway()">+3</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="newGame">
      <button>New Game</button>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to center the new game button that I put in a div class called `newGame` it always stays in the right corner.

Comment: Hi, check your markdown formatting. There is no need for using so big font size

Comment: oh okay sorry, its edited now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see if it works for you, and you can always change the values to match the position of button according to your need.

```
.newGame{
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  top: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

[I guess this is what you are expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLrU7.png)

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what i need but i don't know what does the webkit transform do?

Comment: You can refer this documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/WebKit_Extensions also check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Answer (score 0):

Use flex property  **align-items: center;** to center any div element vertically when flex-direction in horizontal

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: #1b244a;
  width: 575px;
  height: 385px;
}
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
}

.scoreBox {
  background: black;
  width: 155px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.scoreBox h1 {
  font-size: 90px;
  color: red;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-family: "cursed timer", sans-serif;
}

.scoreBtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.scoreBtn button {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-color: #9aabd8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
}
.newGame {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.newGame button {
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="homeTitle">
        <h3>HOME</h3>
        <div class="scoreBox">
          <h1 id="scoreHome">0</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="scoreBtn">
          <button onclick="plusOneHome()">+1</button>
          <button onclick="plusTwoHome()">+2</button>
          <button onclick="plusThreeHome()">+3</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="guestTitle">
        <h3>GUEST</h3>
        <div class="scoreBox">
          <h1 id="scoreAway">0</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="scoreBtn">
          <button onclick="plusOneAway()">+1</button>
          <button onclick="plusTwoAway()">+2</button>
          <button onclick="plusThreeAway()">+3</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="newGame">
        <button>New Game</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but the result is not i wanted tho but i appreciate it.